# When using undetected-chromedriver I can't change the useragent

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, user-agent, fingerprint, undetected-chromedriver

Have anyone faced this issue before? here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


# Define a custom user agent string
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

# Set up Chrome WebDriver with the custom user agent
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = False

chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")

# Initialize the WebDriver with the specified options
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# You can now use the driver with the custom user agent
driver.get("https://amiunique.org/fingerprint")
time.sleep(40)
```

I have tested this method without using undetected-chromedriver uc and the useragent changed, but for some reason when ever I use undetected-chromedriver the useragent refuses to change, any thoughts?

Comment: I assume that's for the best? Maybe it's undetected because it won't let you change the user agent?

Comment: Also, I believe the option has 2 dashes `options.add_argument('--user-agent=')` but maybe that's irrelevant and selenium already fixes that internally?

Comment: The problem is david that I tried on fingerprint,com and it caught the browser fingerprint,